# Java ExcelParser example Import apache error

Tags: java, apache, import

In my code , I am facing apche library missing error..

I paste my whole code below..
pls help me to find the solution ...

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.*;



// Apache POI - HSSF imports
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFDateUtil;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem;




public class ExcelParser {

    HSSFSheet m_sheet;
    int m_iNbRows;
    int m_iCurrentRow = 0;
    private static final String JAVA_TOSTRING =
 "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy";

    public ExcelParser(HSSFSheet sheet)
    {
        m_sheet = sheet;
        m_iNbRows = sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();
    }


    /* Returns the contents of an Excel row in the 
form of a String array.
     * @see com.ibm.ccd.common.parsing.Parser#splitLine()
     */
    public String[] splitLine() throws Exception {
        if (m_iCurrentRow == m_iNbRows)
            return null;

        HSSFRow row = m_sheet.getRow(m_iCurrentRow);
        if(row == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        else
        {
            int cellIndex = 0; 
            int noOfCells = row.getPhysicalNumberOfCells();
            String[] values = new String[noOfCells];        
            short firstCellNum = row.getFirstCellNum();
            short lastCellNum = row.getLastCellNum();

            if (firstCellNum >=0 && lastCellNum >=0) 
            {
                for(short iCurrent = firstCellNum; iCurrent <lastCellNum; iCurrent++) 
            {
                    HSSFCell cell = (HSSFCell)row.getCell(iCurrent);
                    if(cell == null)
                    {
                        values[iCurrent] = "";
                        cellIndex++;                
                        continue;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        switch(cell.getCellType())
                        {                           
                        case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                        double value = cell.getNumericCellValue();
                        if(HSSFDateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)) 

                        {
                            if(HSSFDateUtil.isValidExcelDate(value))
                            {
                                Date date = HSSFDateUtil.getJavaDate(value);
                                SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(JAVA_TOSTRING);  
                                values[iCurrent] = dateFormat.format(date);                             
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                throw new Exception("Invalid Date value found at row number " +
                                        row.getRowNum()+" and column number "+cell.getCellNum());   
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            values[iCurrent] = value + "";
                        }
                        break;

                        case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                            values[iCurrent] = cell.getStringCellValue();
                        break;

                        case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK:
                            values[iCurrent] = null;    
                        break;

                        default:
                            values[iCurrent] = null;    
                        }           
                    }                           
                }        
            }
            m_iCurrentRow++;
            return values;              
        }

    }

   public static void main(String args[])
   {
       HSSFWorkbook workBook = null; 
       File file  = new File("/home/sprasad/austin_api/Book1.xls");
       InputStream excelDocumentStream = null;
       try 
       {
           excelDocumentStream = new FileInputStream(file);
           POIFSFileSystem fsPOI = new POIFSFileSystem(new BufferedInputStream(excelDocumentStream));
           workBook = new HSSFWorkbook(fsPOI);         
           ExcelParser parser = new ExcelParser(workBook.getSheetAt(0));
           String [] res;
            while ((res = parser.splitLine()) != null)
            {
                            for (int i = 0; i < res.length; i++)
                {
                    System.out.println("Token Found [" + res[i] + "]");
                }
            }
            excelDocumentStream.close();

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


   }
```

above example facing error while I am using this code..

Please suggest me any library or tutorial for the same..
Thanks in advance...

Comment: The problem is with your compilation classpath, which you haven't shown us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just download the [Apache POI](http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/poi/release/bin/poi-bin-3.8-20120326.tar.gz), inflate it on your classpath and check if it is working.

If you are using eclipse, just right click on the project > Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries and click on add external JARs.

Following JARs should be added:

- poi-3.8-20120326.jar
- poi-examples-3.8-20120326.jar
- poi-excelant-3.8-20120326.jar
- poi-ooxml-3.8-20120326.jar
- poi-ooxml-schemas-3.8-20120326.jar
- poi-scratchpad-3.8-20120326.jar

After this, you should be able to use the project classes.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an `import` error, then you have probably forgotten to include the 3rd party library that you are using in your [Java classpath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_%28Java%29). Assuming that you have a bunch of JAR files for your Apache libraries, you need to include those in the classpath of your application, as mentioned in the Wikipedia link I supplied.

Alternatively, you may be trying to import outdated or otherwise invalid classes that do not exist in your current library set.

Unless you post the error message and mention *which* library files you are using and how you are launching your application, we cannot really provide more specific help.